# Aptana 3 executing a rake task from a ruble command

Tags: ruby, rake, bundle, aptana

Im all new to this so I have no idea if its possible but all I want to do is execute a rake task from a ruble command in Aptana Studio 3.

The rakefile is located in the project folder and all it does in convert and minimize some sass code.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would first look at http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/A+Simple+Command to get familiar with creating a command in a ruble.

If you wanted to add a rake task to a command in a ruble, I would then look at http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Executing+an+External+Command

Inside the invoke block for the command, you can invoke an external rake task like:

`rake your_rake_task`